# Smooth passage from one graph to another

Tags: r, graphics, graph

Consider the two following graphs

```
require(ggplot2)
set.seed(5276)
my_mtcars = mtcars
my_mtcars$rand = rnorm(nrow(mtcars))

ggplot(my_mtcars, aes(rand, mpg)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

```
ggplot(my_mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

I would like to make a movie (or any animated picture that could easily be introduced in a .ppt) that would make a smooth passage from the first graph toward the second. During the passage, we would see the dots smoothly move horizontally to reach their destination. The x-axis scale and label should also appear (eventually smoothly).

I would try to create many .png that are intermediate pictures and then make a gif out of it using ImageMagick (Bash) but I am pretty sure there should be a better solution. I used `ggplot2` to produce the plots but I am not strict on that. Here is what I tried for the moment

```
IntFormat = function(x,nbdigits=0){
  cx = paste0(x)
  l = length(strsplit(cx,"")[[1]])
  if (nbdigits < l){nbdigits = l; print("WARNING: Parameter `nbdigits` too small")}
  before = paste(rep("0",nbdigits-l), collapse="")
  paste0(before, cx)
}

SmoothGraph = function(x1, x2, y1, y2, times = "NOTSET", ...){
    path = "/Users/remi/Desktop/"
    if (times == "NOTSET") {
        times = c(seq(0,0.1,length.out=10), seq(0,0.2, length.out=5), seq(0.2,0.8, length.out=6), seq(0.8,0.9, length.out=5), seq(0.9,1,length.out=10))
    }
    nbdigits = length(times)
    count = 0
    x1_rel = x1 / (max(x1) - min(x1))
    x1_rel = x1_rel - max(x1_rel) + 1
    x2_rel = x2 / (max(x2) - min(x2))
    x2_rel = x2_rel - max(x2_rel) + 1
    y1_rel = y1 / (max(y1) - min(y1)) - min(y1)
    y1_rel = y1_rel - max(y1_rel) + 1
    y2_rel = y2 / (max(y2) - min(y2)) - min(y2)
    y2_rel = y2_rel - max(y2_rel) + 1
    x_diff = x2_rel - x1_rel
    y_diff = y2_rel - y1_rel
    for (time in times){
        count = count + 1
        xtmp = x1_rel + x_diff * time
        ytmp = y1_rel + y_diff * time
        print(count)
        png(paste0(path, "SmoothGraph_", IntFormat(count, nbdigits=nbdigits), ".png"))
        plot(x=xtmp, y=ytmp, ...)
        dev.off()
    }
    system (command="
    cd /Users/remi/Desktop/
    convert SmoothGraph_*.png -delay 1 SmoothGraph.gif
    rm SmoothGraph_*.png
    ")
}

SmoothGraph(x1=rnorm(12), y1=mtcars$mpg , x2 = mtcars$wt, y2=mtcars$mpg)
```

Comment: Have you looked for animation examples: http://rforpublichealth.blogspot.com/2014/12/animations-and-gifs-using-ggplot2.html ? Have you at least tried to implement it yourself? It's unclear to me what the x-axis would look like during the transition.

Comment: @MrFlick No I haven't tried animation. I added my current trial in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a good fit for the `animation` package. You could do something like this. First, define a function that can interpolate between the two plots

```
framedata<-function(x) {
    subset(transform(my_mtcars, 
        x=rand + x*(wt-rand),
        y=mpg
    ), select=c(x,y))
}
```

Then you can animate them with

```
library(animation)
frame <- seq(0, 1, length.out=20)
saveGIF(lapply(frame, function(f) {
    print( ggplot(framedata(f), aes(x, y)) + geom_point() )
}), "go.gif", interval = 0.05, loop=1)
```

This will create a 20 frame animation with a .05 second delay between frames that plays once.